# intellij - how change the default filename for a class file

Tags: intellij-idea

I small pain I would like to fix

In Intellij and I do file new (php) class

I am coding to WordPress Standards so I want the class name to be First_Letter_Upper_Case and filename to first-letter-upper-case.php but the new class dialog sets it to the same as the class name ( First_Letter_Upper_Case.php )

How can change this behavior?

[image]

Comment: Field `File name` is disabled and you can't rename it by `first-letter-upper-case.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at the moment, see this conversation with jetbrains support:

[image]

Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16269

Also notice the workaround mentioned there:

> As a workaround you can invoke 'Toggle Case' action on file name